# iOS Swift: CollectionView inside TableView with multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have the following design:

A table with multiple sections and multiple rows for each section.
For each row I have a collection view.

I'm having a problem to assign delegates to the collections because of the multiple table sections.

How can I use the collection.tag to refer to a specific section and row of the table view?

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be

1. Create a view controller to hold Table View
2. Create a table view cell to hold collection view
3. Create a collection view cell

And connect the table view's delegate to view controller and connect the collection view's delegate to the table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

Better Approach is to user Section Models

```
struct CellModel {
   var collectionModel: [ModelType] = []
}

struct SectionModel {
    headerModel: Any
    cellModels: [CellModel] = []
}


var sections: [SectionModel] = []
```

// intialize array some where or API Response

in UITabelView delegate method

number of rows

```
return self.sections[section].cellmodels.count
```

number of sections will be

```
return self.sections.count
```

in cell for row at index

```
cell.cellModels = self.sections[indexpath.section].cellModels[indexpath.row]
```

In CellCustomClass

declare `var cellModels: [ModelType] = []`

Now TableCell consist collection view
You can use this array as it data source